# Hadoop streaming fastest way to creat a numpy array

Tags: hadoop, numpy, hadoop-streaming

The input to my mapper is a txt file, which every line is a vector for me.

I want to create a numpy array, where each row will be that vector.

For example: if my text file is:

1 2 3
9 5 7

I want to have a numpy array:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3][9,5,7]])
```

I have(Is there another way..?) to retrieve the lines one by one,
so my question is:
What is the best way to store it so i will create my array in the fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.loadtxt` (and `np.genfromtxt`) reads a text file like that, and produces the array you want.

```
a = np.loadtxt(filename)   # or
a = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=int)
```

This function does read each line, collect the numbers into a list of lists, which it converts to the array at the end.

There are many SO questions about reading 'csv' text files with these functions.  `pandas` has a version that is faster.

---

`loadtxt` takes anyinput that behaves like file `readline` - that is, an iterator that gives one line at a time.

In an interactive session I can define a string with triple quotes, split it into lines, and pass that list of lines to `loadtxt`.

```
In [105]: txt="""1 2 3
4 5 6"""
In [106]: txt=txt.splitlines()
In [107]: np.loadtxt(txt, dtype=int)
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`StringIO` can also be used for this, but a plain list of strings is all you really need.  You can also use `stdin`:

```
In [111]: a=np.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
0 1 2
5 6 7 <ctrlD>

In [112]: a
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.]])
```

Loading `a` and `b` using different columns works - provided you use ctrl D twice.

```
In [114]: a = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin, usecols=(0,1)); b = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin, usecols=[2])
1 2 3
4 5 6 ^D
2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 ^D

In [115]: a
Out[115]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])

In [116]: b
Out[116]: array([ 4.,  8.])
```

Though I suspect you really want to fill `a` and `b` from the same set of lines.  For that you have split the array after loading

```
In [117]: ab = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
1 2 3
4 5 6

In [118]: ab
Out[118]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])

In [119]: a=ab[:,[0,1]]; b=ab[:,[2]]

In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])

In [121]: b
Out[121]: 
array([[ 3.],
       [ 6.]])
```

Comment: in my code im reading from stdin line by line, how does it work with loadtxt?
i first need to creat a textfile (for example with StringIO) and then use it.Is there a fastest way?

Comment: `loadtxt` takes any iterable that gives it text line by line.

Comment: I actually need to the following:
a = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin, usecols=(0,1))
b = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin, usecols=[2])

b is empty, how can i fix this?

Comment: Are trying to load `a` and `b` from subsequent sets of lines, or from the same?  I added both ways.